# SQL Server - why are window functions not permitted in update statements?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

When running an update statement, such as the one below, I get an error telling me that

> Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

```
UPDATE dbo.Dim_Chart_of_Account
SET Account_Order = LAG([Account_Order]) OVER (ORDER BY [Account_SKey])
```

I know that this can be easily worked around using an updatable cte, like below

```
 WITH my_cte AS (
     SELECT [Account_Order], LAG([Account_Order]) OVER (ORDER BY [Account_SKey]) AS acc_order_lag
     FROM Dim_Chart_of_Account
)
UPDATE my_cte
SET [Account_Order] = acc_order_lag
```

My question is, are there any reasons why this is not permitted in an update statement, should I avoid using an updatable cte as a workaround?

My concern is that there are issues when using window functions with update statements and therefore I'd like to understand if this is an acceptable method or should be avoided.

Comment: The updatable CTE is acceptable and fine. No idea why it is not allowed in the UPDATE.

Comment: Maybe Hallowe'en protection of some kind?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Window functions aren't permitted in UPDATE statements because UPDATE isn't compatible with SELECT or ORDER BY.

Window functions are like scoped SELECT statements that re-examine the relevant rows and apply conditions like PARTITION BY and ORDER BY. In addition, many window functions require an ORDER BY clause (ROW_NUMBER, LAG, and FIRST_VALUE, for example).

UPDATE statements use SET instead of SELECT, so SELECT is not allowed anywhere in the same query level. Any SELECT appearing with UPDATE must be contained in a subquery.

Disallowing the ORDER BY makes sense considering an UPDATE statement is indifferent to the order in which it updates rows.

There's no inherent downside to using a CTE or other subquery as a workaround to get an UPDATE to use a window function. That's the common practice advocated by T-SQL experts like Itzik Ben-Gan. (See page 29 of his book, *[Microsoft SQL Server 2012 High-Performance T-SQL Using Window Functions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735658366)* where he covers this exact scenario.)